# Is JSON serialization deterministic?

Tags: json

I am working with an applcation that serializes JSON in a way I did not expect. Is JSON serialization deterministic? In a Chrome console, I see

```
> JSON.stringify(3)
"3"
```

but this application serializes the number 3 to `"3.0"`.

Both are clearly legal according to the JSON spec(s) [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) and [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), as is the serialization `"30.0E-01"`.

Is there anything in the JSON standard that specifies what "canonical" serialization is supposed to produce? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I know there aren't integers, only numbers. Don't care about that. I just want to know if there is any determinism about the JSON serialization. Sounds like there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one specific serializer might produce deterministic output. But there is no standard canonical format (at least widely used, there is [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-staykov-hu-json-canonical-form-00) Internet Draft - but it never became an RFC, and is far from it).

Even if there was a "standard" somewhere, it is not in widespread usage, and so you cannot expect JSON documents to uphold it.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) says (in part):

```
8.3.  String Comparison

   Software implementations are typically required to test names of
   object members for equality.  Implementations that transform the
   textual representation into sequences of Unicode code units and then
   perform the comparison numerically, code unit by code unit, are
   interoperable in the sense that implementations will agree in all
   cases on equality or inequality of two strings.  For example,
   implementations that compare strings with escaped characters
   unconverted may incorrectly find that "a\\b" and "a\u005Cb" are not
   equal.

9.  Parsers

   A JSON parser transforms a JSON text into another representation.  A
   JSON parser MUST accept all texts that conform to the JSON grammar.
   A JSON parser MAY accept non-JSON forms or extensions.

   An implementation may set limits on the size of texts that it
   accepts.  An implementation may set limits on the maximum depth of
   nesting.  An implementation may set limits on the range and precision
   of numbers.  An implementation may set limits on the length and
   character contents of strings.

10.  Generators

   A JSON generator produces JSON text.  The resulting text MUST
   strictly conform to the JSON grammar.
```

This also implies that these representations `"a\\b"` and `"a\u005Cb"` are equally valid; it sounds like there is no favored representation, everything is ok as long as it meets the required grammar.